# Null value in bulk insert Hasura GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, hasura

I am trying to do a multiple insert using a REST API exposed by Hasura (written in GraphQL).
This is my mutation:

```
mutation insertMultipleMeasurements2($payload: [measurements_insert_input!]!) {
  insert_measurements(objects: $payload) {
    returning {
      time
    } 
  }
}
```

and this is the definition of *measurements_insert_input* in the Actions tab:

```
input measurements_insert_input {
  device: String!
  value: numeric!
  variable: String!
}
```

(which btw is the only way I found to insert an object of numeric type in a bulk insert).

When I try to insert something like:

```
[
    {
        "device": "TEST",
        "value": 5630,
        "variable": "Length"
    },
        {
        "device": "TEST",
        "value": 5631,
        "variable": "Length"
    }
]
```

I get:

```
{
    "path": "$",
    "error": "expecting a value for non-nullable variable: \"payload\"",
    "code": "validation-failed"
}
```

I tried many different ways to rewrite my mutation but looks like none worked.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message

> "expecting a value for non-nullable variable: "payload""

you should be passing the array via an object

```
{
  payload: [
    {
    "device": "TEST",
    "value": 5630,
    "variable": "Length"
    },
    {
    "device": "TEST",
    "value": 5631,
    "variable": "Length"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've most likely forgotten to wrap your `objects` with `variables`, like so :

```
yourMutation({
      variables: { objects, on_conflict }
})
```

It's not straightforward if you rely on TS IntelliSense, better check the doc :)